# Does JSF contain any mailing Tag or Library or any mailing functionalities?

Tags: java, email, jsf, jakarta-mail

When a user registers, I just want to send a conformation mail to them.
I am working with JSF.
So I just want to know is there any functionality in JSF to achieve/support mailing.
Do I just need to use the javaMail api??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JavaMail` or [Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/email/) which is a little bit simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Spring Mail? Tutorial here:
[Email Integration in Spring Framework](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/83-email-integration-in-spring-framework-1.html)

Java Mail API is so messy, that I understand people are searching for more. Unfortunately, because there is an implementation in standard, no matter how bad, people are trying rather to deal with it than to write their own. Spring also is using Java Mail API internally.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaMail. I don't understand why you think anyone would provide the same thing twice.

Comment: ya thank u.. just a silly doubt.. I thought people might have found an easier way in jsf.

Comment: @Karthikeyan That continues to make no sense unless you are asking whether JSF includes JavaMail, which it doesn't (although J2EE does), or something else to do the same job, which is subject to my observation above.